How can I fit a table to text width?
How can I make the table fit the width of the text?
Adjustbox doesn't seem to work.
I also tried \resizebox, but it doesn't work either.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}  % Required for longtblr
\usepackage{adjustbox}   % Required for scaling images
\usepackage{xcolor}      % For coloring the table background
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\NewTableCommand\SCC[1]{\SetCell{bg=#1}}  % <--- shortcut color cell

% kefine lengths with proper units
\newlength\colwidth
\newlength\colwidthSingle
\setlength\colwidth{2cm}  
\setlength\colwidthSingle{2.08cm}   

\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{230,230,230}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.96}
\definecolor{groupAcolor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{highlightcolor}{RGB}{248,236,223}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = { Sets of Categories},
label = {tblr:category_table},
]{
  colspec = { X[c,h] Q[c,wd=\colwidth] *{6}{X[c,m, wd=\colwidthSingle]} },
  width=\linewidth,
  hlines,
  vlines,
}

Category  & \SetCell[c=7]{c}  Properties &  & & & & & \\*
% First category
 A  &  \SetCell[c=7]{c,bg=groupAcolor} All Elements in Category A &  &  &  &  &  &   \\*

 % ALL elements in category A
  &   & \SetCell[c=3]{r} \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccccc},
        hlines,
        hline{1,Z}={1pt},
        colsep=3pt,
        rowsep=3pt,
        row{1-Z}={font=\small},
        width=\linewidth,
        }
Subset & \SetCell[c=1]{c} $X_1$ & \SetCell[c=1]{c} $X_2$ & \SetCell[c=1]{c} {Other} &\SetCell[c=1]{c} Count\\
1 & $E_{A1},E_{B1}$ & $E_{A2},E_{B2}$ & $E_{C1}$ & 5 \\
2 & $E_{A1},E_{B1},E_{C1}$ & $E_{A2},E_{B2},E_{C2}$ & -- & 7 \\
\end{tblr} & & &  \SetCell[c=3]{l}  \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccccc},
        hlines,
        hline{1,Z}={1pt},
        colsep=3pt,
        rowsep=3pt,
        row{1-Z}={font=\small},
        width=\linewidth,
        }
Subset & \SetCell[c=1]{c} $X_3$ & \SetCell[c=1]{c} $X_4$ & \SetCell[c=1]{c} {Other} &\SetCell[c=1]{c} Count\\
3 & $E_{k1},E_{k2}$ & $E_{A2},E_{B1}$ & $E_{C2}$ & 5 \\
4 & $E_{k1}$ & $E_{A2}$ & $E_{C2},E_{B1}$ & 3 \\
\end{tblr} \\

& & \SetCell[c=6]{c}{} \\

 % Example values and illustration
 & & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={ccccc},
        hlines,
        hline{2,Z}={1pt},
        hline{1}={white},
        colsep=3pt,
        rowsep=3pt,
        row{1-Z}={font=\small},
        width={3\colwidthSingle+3\tabcolsep}, 
        }

\SetCell[c=5]{c} {\large Normalized Parameters} \\
Config &  $P_A$ &$Q_A$ &$R_A$ & Range  \\

A & $-\dfrac{1}{k}$ & $\dfrac{1}{k}$ & $-P$ & $(-\infty,-1]$ \\ 
B & $-k$ & $1$ & $1$ &  $[-1, 0]$ \\
C & $\dfrac{k}{1+k}$ & $\dfrac{1}{1+k}$ & $1-P$ & $[0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$ \\
\end{tblr} & &  &\SetCell[c=3]{c} \adjincludegraphics[width={3\colwidthSingle+3\tabcolsep}]{example-image-a}   \\

& & \SetCell[c=6]{c}{} \\

 % Family and visual
&  & \SetCell[c=6]{c} Example \\*
& Subset & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Connections &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Value & &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} { Structure \\  ($1=\text{A}$,$\;2=B$,$\;3=C$)}  \\

% Example 1
&  & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}   & &\SetCell[c=2]{c}  \textbf{Struct A} &\\
&  1 &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} \adjincludegraphics[width={2\colwidthSingle+2\tabcolsep}]{example-image-a}  &  &\SetCell[c=2]{c}  \begin{tblr}{
width=0.2\linewidth,
colspec={ll},
hline{2-Y}={solid},
hline{2,Y}={1pt},
row{1-Z}={font=\small},
width={2\colwidthSingle+2\tabcolsep}
}
Element       & Value\\
$E_{A1},E_{B1}$          & $|A-C|$       \\ 
Count: & 5 \\ 
\end{tblr} &    &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}  \adjincludegraphics[width={2\colwidthSingle+2\tabcolsep}]{example-image-a} &\\

% Normalized simulation waveforms
 &  & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Structure & &  &\SetCell[c=3]{c} \adjincludegraphics[width={3\colwidthSingle+3\tabcolsep}]{example-image-a}   \\

\end{longtblr}

\end{document}


For an overview of options see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

It seems your table needs landscape page orientation. I would load a package pdflscape and wrap the whole longtblr around \begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}. if it's not enough, prepend landscape with \newgeometry to reduce margins, e.g. \newgeometry{margin=0.5cm} and append \restoregeometry right after \end{landscape}. If that does not help, you may need to re-design the table.

@Celdor I would like to keep the vertical table instead. Is it possible to use resizebox to reduce the size to make it fit?

My table is much longer, above is just an example part of it so horizontal layout is not prefered here.

Don't use X columns for everything, as they are all the same width whether they contain anything or not.

Fit the width of some table wasting spaces an 2% or  5% is not the same as reducing a table to half.  There is a limit to everything, and you have already crossed the line. If the example represents the true table width, well, forget Jasper's link, load the package geometry, and use the a3paper option in the document class.

@hana In current form, that table would probably fit the page in landscape if you adjust margins. If you need to render it vertically, you will have to rearrange/re-design it. I would not rely on \resizebox at all. The result will be poor and you will end up with something pretty unreadable.

@hana I think, you did as many people do: You overloaded your table with information and you get lost in the possibilities of tabledesign. Take a step back and consider, which information is needed at a point and how you may split your table into subtables, as you did, but do not put them into a main table.

@hana From my point of view, your code and tables are far to complicated. Try to reduce it.
